# Oracle: Dynamic sampling is used by the Optimizer after importing the statistics of a table

Tags: oracle, optimization, rdbms

Here are the steps I did for `scott.emp` table.

1. `select * from emp where empno > 7503`
2. `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor);`

> ```
>    [..]
>    Note
>    -----
>       - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
> ```

3. `exec DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ('scott','EMP');`
4. `select * from emp where empno > 7503.`
5. `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor);`

   ```
   -- No Dynamic sampling used --
   ```
6. Exported the table stats.
7. cleaned up the instance and launch fresh instance.
8. Imported the table stats.
9. `select NUM_ROWS,LAST_ANALYZED,GLOBAL_STATS,USER_STATS from USER_TAB_STATISTICS where table_name ='EMP';`

   ```
    14 28-SEP-16 YES NO
   ```
10. `select * from emp where empno > 7503.`
11. `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor);`

> ```
>  Note
>  -----
>    - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)**
> ```

Why is dynamic sampling used even though table has stats? Do we need to trigger anything after importing the stats?
Why is dynamic sampling not used by the optimizer after gathering stats in first instance (step 5)?

Comment: What version of the database? What exactly does step 7 mean? What statistics did you import on step 8? Is table emp partitioned, do you have statistics on partition for the value 7503? Can you post the full execution plans?

Comment: In 7, uninstalled and reinstalled the DB. In 8, i have imported only table stats. No table is not partitioned one.  Thanks @stefan i got the reason why DS was picked up the optimizer and posted the same in answer section.

Comment: is it 12c database? this is a new feature triggered by 12c feature "adaptive execution plans".

Comment: Yes, it is 12c Database. but the requirement is different that i need to match the execution plans after importing the stats.

Answer (score 0):

Got the reason. In step 8, i'm importing only table stats. If we import db stats, system,dictionary stats then Optimizer wont go for Dynamic sampling.

Optimizer rule : If optimizer doesn't have no/enough stats then it will try to do sampling.

So to simulate the execution plans, one needs to import all the stats.